# package classes does not exist error

Tags: java, awt, package, textfield

I have built my own custom AWT classes in my home folder in java_src/classes.

Each of the java files contain the `package classes;` declaration at the top.

I also created a sample program called `ScreenDemo.java` and placed it in the java_src/ folder to use the custom AWT classes instead of `java.awt`.

```
//ScreenDemo.java
import classes.Screen;
class ScreenDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Screen.init(20,15,3);
    }
}
```

But when i attempt to compile ScreenDemo.java,an error is displayed

```
java_src/ScreenDemo.java:1: package classes does not exist
import classes.Screen;
          ^
java_src/ScreenDemo.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Screen
location: class ScreenDemo
        Screen.init(20,15,3);
        ^
2 errors
```

When i add the path i encounter this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ScreenSample (wrong name:                   classes/ScreenSample)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)
Could not find the main class: ScreenSample. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Add path till `java_src\` where your package folder is present, to your classpath..

Comment: What's you compilation command (ie the `javac` command) you are using?

Comment: @MadProgrammer javac java_src/ScreenDemo.java

Comment: @NandkumarTekale  it is in the java_src folder

Comment: @Gambler.. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: @Gambler: your `Screen` class is under `java_src/classes` and you are creating `ScreenDemo` class under `java_src/` that's why it might having problem.
try to make your `ScreenDemo` class in other directory, like: `java_src/demo/`. and also add `java_src/classes` to your classpath before compiling

Answer (score 0):

While compiling the code the compiler is complaining about the missing class Screen.java which i assume is inside "classes" package.

Either you need to add src\classes\ to the src folder list or move the Screen.java to the same location as ScreenDemo.java and then try to compile again.

Comment: how to add src\classes to src folder list dude?

Comment: If you are using command line then look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile